# How do I create a response document from an action on a form in Lotus Domino Designer?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I have 2 forms:

1. `Document`
2. `Response`

How to add Response form to Documents forms, I nothing found in properties.

I'm using Domino designer 8.

Comment: This question is not understandable, please describe better, what you want to achieve. If you simply want to create a response, then the form needs to be a response (properties of form, first Tab), and then you use @Command( [Compose]; "Response" ) when a "normal" document is open or selected...

Comment: @TorstenLink in Document form I add action to open Response `@Command([Compose];"Atsakas")` , but when I try press actino link I get error: `No document is selected; please select a document to respond to.`I think that must be setting that form "Response" is response to form "Document"

Comment: You have to save the "main"- document before creating a response document works. That is why the error message appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a response document all of the below have to be true:

1. The Form has to be a "Response" in its properties
2. For view- actions a document (that will become the "main"- document for the response) has to be selected in a view
3. For form- actions the document has to be SAVED at least once. You cannot add a respoonse to an unsafed main- document.

If neither 2 or 3 is true, then the message `No document is selected...` will appear.

If it works, you will find an item "$Ref" in the properties of the response, that contains the Universal- ID of the parent document.